# Why "strcat already defined in ***.obj"?

Tags: c, error-handling, stdio, strcat

I only use `#include <stdio.h>` in

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcat(char* s, char* t);

int main()
{
    char str1[12] = "hello";
    char str2[] = ",world";
    strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}

void strcat(char* s, char* t)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(*s != '\0')
        i++;

    while((*(s + i++) = *(t + j++)) != '\0');

}
```

But when I build  it, the console outputs:

```
--------------------Configuration: test16 - Win32 Debug--------------------
Linking...
LIBCD.lib(strcat.obj) : error LNK2005: _strcat already defined in test16src.obj
```

Why? Does `strcat` exist in `stdio.h`?

PS:
  Can you explain the link error by describing the progress when it is linked with other files?

Comment: Headers and libraries don't correspond one-to-one in C, and are handled at completely different stages of compilation.

Comment: As a site note, it is a bad idea to have a function that has the name of a C library function, has almost the same semantic as that, but still has a different prototype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strcat` is a C library function. See [`man strcat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncat.3.html) or [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcat.html) ([or here fo windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282.aspx)) or in `string.h` ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/string.h.html)).

So the symbol `strcat` is used in the standard C libray (LIBCD here) which is linked against the program automagically during the link phase, where the error you show occurs.

The error informs you that the symbol `strcat` as defined by the object file `test16src.o` as created by compiling your sources already exists in the standard library (LIBCD) linked to `test16src.o` to create the final executable.

The get around this symbol name clash use a different name for your implementation, like for example `my_strcat()`.

Comment: But I haven't used "#include <string.h>".@alk

Comment: @alk: probably someone who doesn't know what to do with `man strcat` (+1)

Comment: @Rubby, while usually identifiers are only reserved when you include the corresponding header, there are some that are always reserved. In particular names starting with `str` are of that kind.

Comment: @alk,Can you explain the link error by describing the progress when it is linked with other files?

Comment: @Rubby: I do not understand your question. Which "*other files*" are you referring to, please? Does this help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f.aspx